# Making a diagram like this in TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to make two diagrams, along [these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ife.png): [image: like this]

I'm having trouble finding a way to do it most simply, I've been able to do it with bubbles which I then don't draw the borders of, but that leaves a lot of extra space and there must be a better way to do it. Most importantly, I'd like to be able for "General" and "Particular" in the top diagram to *each* branch off into their own tree, instead of just the latter. I've tried doing this, but I can't make it look symmetrical. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ball/.style = {circle, draw=none, anchor=base, align=center, inner sep=0}]
\node[ball](sci) at (0, 4) {{\large A}\\
Text\\
Here};

\node[ball](grm) at (0, 2) {{\large B}\\
Text\\
Here};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=1.25cm,anchor=base](1.5,0) -- (1.5,3.5) node [black,midway,xshift=1.6cm,yshift=-0.15cm] {\large Genus of A and B};
%\node[ball](abs) at (6, 3) {{\large C}\\
%Long text here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you show us what you've tried so far, in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? That way, it's easier for us to get started working on a solution, plus we'll know where to focus our explanations vs. just typing the code and giving you the complete diagram.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I've added my MWE. As you can see, it's fairly far off the mark. I would have thought this question was inappropriate were it not for the noted lack of diagrams of this sort on any of the reference materials and example websites I've been able to get my hands on.

Comment: Please complete your code to make it compile i.e. start with `\documentclass...` and end with `\end{document}`. Especially crucial for TiKZ. The links we posted explain how to make an MWE.

Comment: That doesn't add anything important, but OK.

Comment: I find the diagrams very unclear. It looks to me as if the left curly parentheses on the first row are actually errors, because there should be two rows, to indicate the analogies more clearly.

Comment: There are no errors, as they are not analogies. The general and particular both belong to the individual. The universal is distinct from either. The same goes for the collective and singular, both belonging to the particular.

Comment: You could try the [`schemata`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/schemata)-package.

Comment: That looks very promising. I'll do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[image: The output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sub}[2]{\begin{tabular}{p{3.9cm}}#1 \\ #2 \end{tabular} }
\newcommand{\psub}[2]{\(\biggl\{\)\sub{#1}{#2}}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
\sub{Universal}{Individual} & \psub{General}{Particular} & \psub{Collective}{Singular} \\
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[8pt]
Universal & \psub{The Unmanifested}{Formal Manifestation} \\
Individual & Formal Manifestation & \psub{Subtle state}{Gross state}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is enough of a push in the right direction for me to get what I want.

Comment: However, the top diagram actually has three levels. The particular is the genus of both the collective and the singular (and the individual the genus of the general and particular). I would be able to do that, but not center them as well as in the picture (it would end up being below "Particular" instead of centered next to it). How would I be able to do that?

Comment: To make the diagram clearer, you might try to use a TiKZ tree, like in this example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/

Answer (score 3):

With stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\stacktype{L}
\begin{document}
\stackunder{Universal}{%
  Individual\hspace{1in}\scalerel[2.3ex]{\{\ }{\stackanchor{General}
    {Particular\hspace{1in}\smash{%
      \scalerel[2.3ex]{\{\ }{\stackanchor{Collective}{Singular}}}}
}}\par\bigskip\medskip
\rule{4.5in}{3pt}\par\medskip
\stackunder{Universal}{%
  \hspace{1.3in}\scalerel[2.3ex]{\{\ }{\stackanchor{The Unmanifested}
    {Formless Manifestation}
}}\par\bigskip
\stackunder{Individual}{%
  \hspace{1.5in}
    Formal Manifestation\hspace{.6in}\smash{%
      \scalerel[2.3ex]{\{\ }{\stackanchor{Subtle state}{Gross state}}}}
\par\bigskip
\end{document}
```

[image]